# Is there a way to remove files belongs to a partition without physically delete them in iceberg?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

there is [add_files()](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#add_files) to add some files from hive table to iceberg. but cannot find a way to reverse that operation other than drop the table and recreate.

```
CALL spark_catalog.system.add_files(
table => 'db.tbl',
source_table => 'db.src_tbl',
partition_filter => map('date', '2023-03-16', 'hour', '12')
```

every thing works expected till this step, but now if i want to add all files belongs to `2023-03-16` now it will complain some files is duplicate.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot complete import because data files to be imported already exist within the target table: 
.../part-00000-d9d0137c-d7d6-46f5-b78a-9f68b977c7af.c000.zstd.parquet.  
This is disabled by default as Iceberg is not designed for multiple references to the same file within the same table.  
If you are sure, you may set 'check_duplicate_files' to false to force the import.
```

obviously don't want to add duplicate either. is there a solution?

Comment: Did you try to rollback the table to the previous snapshot?

Comment: yes. that is what did. not straightforward but yes work with some tweak. https://apache-iceberg.slack.com/archives/C025PH0G1D4/p1679005212089589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summary from the community [slack thread](https://apache-iceberg.slack.com/archives/C025PH0G1D4/p1679005212089589).

- use [snapshot management procedure](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/#snapshot-management), it's pretty convolved.
- use [`delete from`](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-writes/#delete-from) as it's metadata only delete if filter matches whole partition and won't touch the data.